# Magnetic compass correction

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-4, compass

After updating to Android 4.4.3 the magnetic compass deviates by 90 degrees. This is more than a lttle bit and recalibrating did not help.

Q1: Is this a common problem?

Q2: Is there a fix or workaround?

Comment: Have you tried to re-calibrate the compass? See: [How can I calibrate the compass on my phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/10145/16575) / [How does compass calibration work?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30329/16575) / [How can I get my compass pointing the right direction?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/24003/16575) / Google Search on [android compass calibration](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+compass+calibration&ie=UTF-8&nfpr=1) gives even video tutorials on this.

Comment: @Izzy Yes I tried to recalibrate that does not change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen some other reports avlbout 90 degree compass deviations, and they were reported on android 4.4.3.

Now that was an extremely short lived version.

On 4.4.4 the problem vanished. So I am still convinced that this was a 4.4.3 problem.